# bump text up in a textbox

Tags: c#

If I had a TextBox that is 32 lines high.
How could I "Bump" the current text in the TextBox down 1 then prepend the new text on the first line.

This is what I tried it doesn't work and is obviously not a clean/efficient way of doing something

```
String[] chat = new String[32];

if (client.Controls[0].InvokeRequired)
{
    SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(setText);
    client.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
}
else
{
    chat[0] = chat[1].ToString();
    chat[1] = chat[2].ToString();
    chat[2] = chat[3].ToString();
    chat[3] = chat[4].ToString();
    chat[4] = chat[5].ToString();
    chat[5] = chat[6].ToString();
    chat[6] = chat[7].ToString();
    chat[7] = chat[8].ToString();
    chat[8] = chat[9].ToString();
    chat[9] = chat[10].ToString();
    chat[10] = chat[11].ToString();
    chat[11] = chat[12].ToString();
    chat[12] = chat[13].ToString();
    chat[13] = chat[14].ToString();
    chat[14] = chat[15].ToString();
    chat[15] = chat[16].ToString();
    chat[16] = chat[17].ToString();
    chat[17] = chat[18].ToString();
    chat[18] = chat[19].ToString();
    chat[19] = chat[20].ToString();
    chat[20] = chat[21].ToString();
    chat[21] = chat[22].ToString();
    chat[22] = chat[23].ToString();
    chat[23] = chat[24].ToString();
    chat[24] = chat[25].ToString();
    chat[25] = chat[26].ToString();
    chat[26] = chat[27].ToString();
    chat[27] = chat[28].ToString();
    chat[28] = chat[29].ToString();
    chat[29] = chat[30].ToString();
    chat[30] = chat[31].ToString();
    chat[31] = text + "\r\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < chat.Length; i++)
    {
        if (chat[i] != null)
        {
            client.Controls[0].Text += text + "\r\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you might find a `ListBox` is more suitable than a `TextBox` for this use case.

Comment: what happens in the first for-loop?

Comment: @FlorisPrijt nothing it was just to initiate all strings with "" but then I took it out and made the array pre defined as ""

Answer (score 0):

Im a bit confused with a question. 
a) add loop i.e.

```
for (int i= 0; i<31; i++)
   chat[i] = chat[i+1].ToString();
chat[31] = text + "\r\n";
```

b) u need to change textbox data, if u changed a variables, unless it is binded

or post about what u wanna with new text in first line. At least i didnt get that.

Comment: I'm sorry the only thing I understood from what you said is the code, can you rephrase what you said in proper English please.

Comment: u = you, wanna = want to, if he i.e. made textbox.text = chat[1]; and after changed variable, it will not show the change in text box. As said, i dint get that from the question

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look very efficient. What is the purpose of your application? Is this a 'Chat' application?

Is there any reason for keeping 32 strings in an array?

Why not simply append the new string to the top of the text contained in the textbox for example,

```
client.Controls[0].Text = [Some Text] + Environment.Newline + client.Controls[0].Text;
```

Comment: The reason why I used an array length of 32 is because that's the max number of lines I want to be displayed at one time. Where pre pending the text is fine it will store in viewable text which is pointless

Comment: Then you can simply keep a counter in memory and remove the last line from your string when 32 is reached.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly what I wanted but it works.

```
        public void setText(string text)
        {
            if (ChatClient.ChatClient.client.Controls[0].InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(setText);
                client.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                client.Controls[0].Text = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < chat.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    chat[i] = chat[i + 1];
                }

                chat[30] = text;

                for (int i = 0; i < chat.Length; i++)
                {
                    client.Controls[0].Text += chat[i] + "\r\n";
                }
}
```